# Attached all images from taxonomy in view

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I am creating a view of a content type and content type is linked with you to taxonomy with has images.

Now, i have added Relaionship as well.

But now if my node is attached to muliple taxmony term it is showing results seperatlety for each row.

i want one main nid against all taxonmy items with images in it within view.

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of Display modes. You can find them under Structure > Display modes > View modes. Don't confuse them with Views module, they use the same word "views" but are two different features. You need to combine those two features to display referenced Taxonomy field fields on Content Views.

1. Create a new View mode for Taxonomy term under Structure > Display modes > View modes
2. Enable it on the Manage display page for the Taxonomy vocabulary (the one with images), a new subtab will appear on that page where you can edit which term fields should display under that mode (Disable Description and any other fields you don't want to show, but keep the Image)
3. Edit your Content Views, edit the Taxonomy term field and set the `Formatter` to `Rendered entity`
4. Set the `View mode` to the one you created in step 1. Make sure that you have `Display all values in the same row` under `Multiple field settings` but you probably already have that.
5. Remove the Relationship unless you need it for something else. Display mode pulls in the term image information, you don't need the Relationship to do that.